# Ipython auto-complete in Enthought Python Distribution

Tags: python, python-2.7, autocomplete, ipython

I have installed the Enthought Python Distribution(academic license) on my 64-bit Windows machine. Since the I am using the academic license, it is the full EPD package(professional version) that got installed. Though all the packages and features(at least the ones I have tried) are working fine, I am having problem with auto complete in Ipython. On press of  the options for auto complete are coming but on pressing  again, it is not highlighting the options. Since there is no highlighting, there is no way of selecting the options either.

I have read the other similar questions in stackoverflow. The solution seems to be: install pyreadline. Though I have done that Ipython auto complete is still not providing me with highlighting of the options on pressing .

**Update:** I just checked the Enthought site. They have launched a newer version called Canopy. However, I do not want to upgrade to Canopy right now, as I have some projects going on and I do not want to risk breaking things right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Be sure you've updated ipython using enpkg as described here: https://support.enthought.com/entries/22415022
2. EPD already comes with pyreadline. I would be surprised if installing pyreadline separately would help.
3. What highlighting are you expecting? I may be misunderstanding you, but IPython terminal's autocomplete is terminal-style (Press Tab, see your options, type some more characters, press Tab again, etc). Highlighting is not intrinsic to this process.
4. You can run EPD and Canopy in parallel as described here:
   https://support.enthought.com/entries/23614903

Comment: Doesn't IPython let me select the option from the auto-complete suggestions? I though pressing <TAB> allows to cycle through the suggestions and select the appropriate one.

Comment: I was describing Ipython terminal, which auto-completes like a bash shell, not like Windows cmd.exe. If you are describing QTConsole (which does not use pyreadline at all IIRC) then yes, pressing Tab does cycle you through the selections. The way to start QTconsole is to type "ipython qtconsole" at a cmd prompt. (The EPD 7.3 start menu  shortcut does not work with the recent versions of IPython, because QTConsole's startup syntax has changed -- it was formerly "ipython-qtconsole")

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan. Starting it from cmd sorts the problem. I was mentioning the qtconsole. My mistake for not being explicit.